# How can I make my crinkles less dry?

Tags: baking, cookies, texture

I just made chocolate crinkles for the first time and I really like them, but they are a bit too dry, making them slightly crumbly. It's possible I over-baked them a little bit, I'll try to bake them a minute less next time. Is there something else I can do to get them some more moist?

I halfed [this](http://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/chocolate_crinkles/) recipe, resulting in:

> 41 g cocoa powder
> 75 g sugar
> 60 ml oil
> 2 eggs
> 1 tsp vanilla
> 130 g flour
> 1 tsp baking powder
> 1/4 tsp salt

I followed the recipe closely for the preparation and I let the dough chill overnight.

Comment: I have made [this recipe](http://www.joyofbaking.com/ChocolateCrinkles.html) several times and they were definitely not dry (though they do dry out somewhat faster than other cookies). It uses melted chocolate instead of cocoa powder and oil, so it's a little hard to see how to modify yours by comparison, though, and I haven't made any others. (My guess would be a bit more sugar and oil and a bit less flour, but I'm not an expert here.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing part of the sugar with a liquid alternative: molasses, maple syrup, honey, et cetera. You don't need to modify it much to start with, try replacing 10 grams of the sugar with 10 grams of an alternative.

Volume conversions can be found in section 1.2 of

http://realfoodliving.com/faqs/sweeteners-faqs

but I can't find any weight conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a small piece of butter the next day when I'm preparing to bake it ..
Then after its out the oven cover it so the hear keeps it a bet more moist !